# How can I insert an item into a list after comparing the previous and next items in Dart?

Tags: dart

I will explain what I'm trying to achieve after I provide some sample code. Firstly, I've written an extension on `List<T>`.

```dart
extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  void place(T item, bool Function(T? prev, T curr, T? next) comparator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      T? prev;
      try {
        prev = elementAtOrNull(i - 1);
        // ignore: avoid_catching_errors
      } on RangeError {
        prev = null;
      }
      final next = elementAtOrNull(i + 1);

      final check = comparator(prev, item, next);
      if (check) {
        insert(i, item);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how my test looks like:

```dart
void main() {
  bool comparator(int? prev, int curr, int? next) {
    if (next == null) {
      return true;
    }

    if (prev == null && curr < next) {
      return true;
    }

    if (curr >= prev! && curr < next) {
      return true;
    }

    if (curr >= prev && curr < next) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  test('place', () {
    final list = [1];

    // ignore: cascade_invocations
    list.place(2, comparator);
    expect(list, [1, 2]);

    list.place(4, comparator);
    expect(list, [1, 2, 4]);

    list.place(3, comparator);
    expect(list, [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  });
}
```

Now, onto the explanation: I want to create a method for `List<T>`, which will insert an item/element into it. It will iterate over each item, compare the given item to the previous and next one and insert it with the condition provided by `comparator` function (which is shamelessly named `place`).

What I basically want to do is to create a list that is ordered, but instead of using `order` and methods alike, I want to do it on the fly.

Probably the implementation of `order` and similar methods are safer and much more performant. The reason I want to do this is because the datatype I'm planning to use is much more complex and it is provided via a Stream, so it's naturally unordered and unpredictable and I don't want to mangle the order of my `ListView` after bloc emits the list once again.

The problem with this implementation at hand is it, for some weird reason, hangs. The test never finishes for some reason. I can't seem to understand the reason.

And also I'd like to get your opinion about this approach. I think there's a hidden performance cost that I can't wrap my head around. Maybe there's a better type of collection that I can do these kind of things. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "place" (which is a sorted `insert`ion) has two issues:

1. You never `break` or `return`. This is the larger issue. You keep appending elements, so the loop keeps running, and the memory keeps filling up, but you don't `return` or `break`. You should `return` or `break` after inserting.
2. `next` is `i`, not `i+1`. `i+1` skips the `i`th element.
3. You don't deal with the possibility than an item has to be added at the end. This can be done with a fallthrough `add` if you use an early `return`.

Here's the fixed `place`:

```dart
extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  void place(T item, bool Function(T? prev, T curr, T? next) comparator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      // Don't abuse errors, it's dirty and inefficient.
      T? prev = i > 0 ? elementAtOrNull(i - 1) : null;
      final next = elementAtOrNull(i);
      final check = comparator(prev, item, next);
      if (check) {
        insert(i, item);
        return; // otherwise we may insert multiple times or even loop forever!
      }
    }
    add(item); // add to end if no place from 0 to length-1 found
  }
}
```

Now your comparator blows up with "Null check operator used on a null value". I can't quite make sense of it; typically comparators compare two values, not three. I don't see why you need both. I'd rewrite it to only compare against one value, reporting whether we are smaller than that value. Let's adapt `place`:

```dart
extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  void place(T item, bool Function(T item, T next) less_than) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      final next = elementAt(i);
      if (less_than(item, next)) {
        insert(i, item);
        return; // otherwise we may insert multiple times or even loop forever!
      }
    }
    add(item); // add to end if no place from 0 to length-1 found
  }
}
```

Your comparator then simplifies to

```dart
final comparator = (int item, int next) => item < next;
```

and everything works as expected.

---

It sounds like you want a sorted set ([`SplayTreeSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html)) or sorted map rather than a list. Maintaining a sorted list is expensive since insertion is a linear time operation. Overall you'll be doing insertionsort on the stream, which gives you poor O(n²) performance. A sorted set will give you O(n log n) performance instead, which is way better. It's also usually more ergonomic to use.

Comment: Just saying, `SplayTreeSet` being a `Set`, it won't allow two identical items in the collection.

Comment: @d-markey indeed. A simple way to make a multiset wrapper is to have your items be "buckets" (lists) of "equal" values which are compared and hashed based on only their first value. Or you could use a `SplayTreeMap`, choose one representative as key, and have all members of the equivalence class comprise the value, which should then be a list of items.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in `place` seems wrong as you're not considering element at index `i`. Also, if the list is empty, `insert` will never be called.

Maybe this would fix it:

```
extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  void place(T item, bool Function(T? prev, T curr, T? next) comparator) {
    T? prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      final next = this[i];

      final check = comparator(prev, item, next);
      if (check) {
        insert(i, item);
        return;
      }

      prev = next;
    }
    // comparator is never called with next = null
    add(item);
  }
}
```

In terms of efficiency this approach is probably wrong. The list is always sorted but insertion will scan it again and again for each new item. If your stream is sorted already, each insertion will scan the whole list, and time complexity will be quadratic = O(n*n). You should try with dichotomy to find the proper insertion point.